# How to Get Certain Data Within a Pandas Column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am making a table and grouping it by a variable called 'passer_player_name'

```
data.loc[(data['play_type'] == 'pass') & (data['down'] <= 4)].groupby(by='passer_player_name')[['epa']].mean()
passer_index = data.loc[(data['play_type'] == 'pass') & (data['down'] <= 4)].groupby(by='passer_player_name')[['epa', 'success','yards_gained']].mean()
passer_index['attempts'] = data.loc[(data['play_type'] == 'pass') & (data['down'] <= 4)].groupby(by='passer_player_name')['epa'].count()
```

This gave the following output (a few example lines):

```
                      epa  success  yards_gained  attempts
passer_player_name      
L.Jackson           0.336     0.48           6.9       335
K.Cousins           0.295     0.50           7.1       363
P.Mahomes           0.285     0.50           7.4       368
```

What I am trying to do next required me to grab/sort my table by using the 'passer_player_name' column, however that is technically not part of the table. I tried doing the following:

```
passer_index['team_names'] = data.loc[(data['play_type'] == 'pass') & (data['down'] <= 4)].groupby(by='passer_player_name').posteam
```

Unfortunately, this gave the following in the added 'team_names' column (this is one example row):

```
(L.Jackson, [BAL, BAL, BAL, BAL, BAL, BAL, BAL...
```

How would I get a column that simply says the team's name once, like a column that would just have the output 'BAL' (obviously different for each player's team)?

To dumb it down because I obviously cannot show the whole dataset and where the data is coming from, my question is essentially the following:

How do I get from the line that says:

```
(L.Jackson, [BAL, BAL, BAL, BAL, BAL, BAL, BAL...
```

To just a line that says 'BAL'? How do I extract that data from this series/sequence/whatever?

Comment: I updated with all teams

Answer (score 0):

Create a map for the team names like this:

```
r = {'K.Murray': 'ARI',
 'M.Ryan': 'ATL',
 'L.Jackson': 'BAL',
 'J.Allen': 'BUF',
 'K.Allen': 'CAR',
 'M.Trubisky': 'CHI',
 'A.Dalton': 'CIN',
 'B.Mayfield': 'CLE',
 'D.Prescott': 'DAL',
 'D.Lock': 'DEN',
 'D.Blough': 'DET',
 'A.Rodgers': 'GRE',
 'D.Watson': 'HOU',
 'J.Brissett': 'IND',
 'N.Foles': 'JAC',
 'P.Mahomes': 'KAN',
 'P.Rivers': 'LOS',
 'J.Goff': 'LOS',
 'R.Fitzpatrick': 'MIA',
 'K.Cousins': 'MIN',
 'T.Brady': 'NEP',
 'D.Brees': 'NOS',
 'D.Jones': 'NYG',
 'S.Darnold': 'NYJ',
 'D.Carr': 'OAK',
 'C.Wentz': 'PHI',
 'D.Hodges': 'PIT',
 'J.Garoppolo': 'SAN',
 'R.Wilson': 'SEA',
 'J.Winston': 'TAM',
 'R.Tannehill': 'TEN',
 'D.Haskins': 'WAS'}
```

Then you can merge like this:

```
data['team_names'] = data.index.map(r)
```

output:

```
                      epa  success  yards_gained  attempts team_names
passer_player_name                                                        
L.Jackson           0.336     0.48           6.9       335        BAL
K.Cousins           0.295     0.50           7.1       363        MIN
P.Mahomes           0.285     0.50           7.4       368        KCC
```

I wrote an html **scraper** that with suggestion i could change to help you, it grabs all the rushing information from https://fantasyfootballers.org/rb-running-back-nfl-stats/. This should work to scrape any table on a site as long as the #Look for table section has the right 'table' index, as there are usually a few tables before the data you want to get, so feel free to try it on other sites. I used it to get the QB's for you from from wikipedia, and the line just had to be table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

```
import requests
import csv, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Main function
def getNFLContent(link, filename):
    #Request content
    result1 = requests.get(link)

    #Save source in var
    src1 = result1.content

    #Activate soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src1,'lxml')

    #Look for table
    table = soup.find_all('table')[1]

    #Save in csv
    with open(filename,'w',newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for tr in table('tr'):
            #print(tr)
            row = [t.get_text(strip=True)for t in tr(['td','th'])]
            writer.writerow(row)


def abrvname(x):
   initial = x[0].capitalize()
   lnamepat = r'(\w*?$)'
   lname = re.search(lnamepat, x).groups()[0]
   return initial + '.' + lname

link = 'https://fantasyfootballers.org/rb-running-back-nfl-stats/'
filename='rbs.csv'
getNFLContent(link, filename)
df = pd.read_csv('rbs.csv')
df.insert(loc=1, column='abr_name', value=df.Name.apply(abrvname))
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but is there any way to just pull out the team abbreviation? I have a rushing index as well but I don't restrict that by attempts for certain reasons, and I don't want to have to write out every single player's name and create a massive map.

Comment: @jakesanghavi would like to help you more as i'm working on this anyway for a side project, i updated my answer. You can probably scrape any football table data you want from any page as long as you reference the right index of the table your searching for. Not sure if this helps. Let me know